# How to Break Line after text in a Listbox in vb

Tags: vb.net

Hey guys I need a little help, Basically I finally got my query button to work, so now when I type something in my text box and press the "query" button, the information from my access database gets shown in my list box.

Now all I need to do is break the line after each title. For example with my current code the information is displayed like:

> Durrant,Terrance,4045550711,11111,e.durrant@live.com.

I would like to have the last block of information with is going to be the "Notes" title displayed under the information like this...

```
Durrant,Eric,4045558999,111111,e.durrant@live.com
This user needed a password reset. I also updated some information in his account.
```

So bascialy I need the "notes" section to be displayed under the other information. I tried different line break techniques like & vbCrLf &, but still doesn't work. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim SQL As String = ("SELECT FirstName, LastName, Phone, UserID, 
    Email, OtherEmail, Notes FROM info WHERE FirstName = ?")

Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtFirstName.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txtLastName.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", txtPhone.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", txtUserID.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", txtEmail.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", txtOtherOptionTxt.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", txtCallDetail.Text) 

    lbLogLaInfo.Items.Add(txtFirstName.Text)

    con.Open()

    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    lbLogLaInfo.Items.Clear()

    While reader.Read()
        lbLogLaInfo.Items.Add(String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}", _
            reader.Item(0).ToString, reader.Item(1).ToString, reader.Item(2).ToString, _
            reader.Item(3).ToString, reader.Item(4).ToString, reader.Item(5).ToString(), _
            reader.Item(6).ToString()))

        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {6}", reader("FirstName"), reader("LastName"), _
            reader("Phone"), reader("UserID"), reader("Email"), reader("OtherEmail"), ("Notes"))
    End While

    reader.Close()
End Using'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [`Environment.Newline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

```
Dim Result = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Line, Environment.Newline, Line2)
```

Following on from your comments...

```
lbLogLaInfo.Items.Add(String.Format("{1},{0},{2},{0},",
                                    Environment.NewLine,
                                    reader.Item(0),
                                    reader.Item(1)))
```

Note the first parameter, the "Format string" is now 1,0,2,0. The numbers refer to the position of the following variables, starting with a 0. The string will look like `"Item0,\n,Item1,\n"`. The `.ToString()` is implied automatically.

If you add a breakpoint after you add each line and examine the contents of `lbLogLaInfo.Items` you will see strings with new lines embedded in them.

I think you may also be hitting a second issue, that the `Listbox` control [doesn't support](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/b1b93015-ea05-4fc7-9675-9af4d227c1a6/write-a-long-string-in-listbox-multiple-lines) multi-line elements.

#### Option 1

For logging, either use a TextBox or, better yet, a RichTextBox as it gives you more control, supports scrolling to the end, etc...

```
RtLog.SelectionStart = RtLog.TextLength
RtLog.SelectionColor = Color.Navy ''This line is optional, just showing capabilities
RtLog.SelectedText = String.Format("{1},{0},{2},{0},",
                                    Environment.NewLine,
                                    reader.Item(0),
                                    reader.Item(1))
RtLog.ScrollToCaret()
```

#### Option 2

You could just cheat and just add multiple entries

```
lbLogLaInfo.Items.Add(reader.Item(0).ToString)
lbLogLaInfo.Items.Add(reader.Item(1).ToString)
```

This would show on multiple lines with the ListBox but make it harder to handle the user clicking on a row and identifying which one it is (assuming you use that functionality).

Comment: Hey Basic, Thanks for the fast response. I tried the technique you suggested. but instead of putting the next set of information on a new line it just deletes it. am I missing something? here is my code

Comment: `lbLogLaInfo.Items.Add(String.Format("{0},{1}", reader.Item(0).ToString, Environment.NewLine, reader.Item(1).ToString, Environment.NewLine`

Comment: Close but not quite... The numbers inside the first string just refer to position of the variables. As to the 2nd part, I apologise, I mis-read and didn't see you were in a ListBox. Multi-line is not supported by default (it uses distance from top of the control to determine item position when clicking. This assumes all elements are the same height). You'll either need to implement your own control or switch to a different control entirely. I've edited to include an alternative. Let me know if it's not helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can add `vbCrLf` to `String.Format` to add a newline as follows:

```vb
lbLogLaInfo.Items.Add(String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}" & vbCrLf & "{6}", _
    reader.Item(0).ToString, reader.Item(1).ToString, reader.Item(2).ToString, _
    reader.Item(3).ToString, reader.Item(4).ToString, reader.Item(5).ToString(), _
    reader.Item(6).ToString()))
```

`String.Format` is specifying the layout to use so you put your new line in the `format` portion of the method.

However, if what @Basic says is true

> ...Listbox control doesn't support multiline...

you may have difficulty seeing this unless you use another control.